Dishwasher - spray arm over utensils drawer keeps falling off
Dishwasher in question is Whirlpool's Sixth Sense line (ADG 7510), which has an utensil drawer at the top, with dedicated small spray arm.
And it keeps falling off. As far as I can tell, it's because it clips spoon(s) in the rack. I am unsure, though, because:

they're placed more or less according to the manual
it is not a regular occurrence.

I am being defeated by my wife's argument, that she is using it according to the manual. Obviously, she's wrong. But I can't get her to arrange them spoons with the heads away from the center, because then they're not completely clean.
Do I insist on flipping the spoons away from spray arm or something else is at play? Maybe replace that spray arm? The dishwasher is at least 5 years old, I already replaced the middle spray arm, for other reasons, so I am aware parts do get used up.
PS. by the upper "spray arm" I mean: the spinning impeller in the middle of the dishwasher's ceiling, over the drawer with utensils. Below is the 1:1 scale (if you click to enlarge it) picture of it:


Get a copy of the manufacturer's manual. See if it has instructions for use of that tray. If they support you, show them to your wife. If not, contact the manufacturer and ask them why this keeps happening and whether you might still be able to get a repair under warranty. They know the quirks of that Mach be; mist of us don't, and can't really guess without a lot more detail (preferably examining it ourselves)

run it empty to see if it still falls off

The manual for the ADG 7510 says there are two rinse arms that can come off for cleaning. If the arm that is falling off is one of these two, then perhaps it's not being screwed back on properly. If there is a third arm in the machine, perhaps the arm itself or its mounting point are worn or a clip is missing. You might have to call the manufacturer and get some help.

@keshlam - Unfortunately, my wife shut me down: she is following the manual. The customer service contact might be a good option, because - yes, it looks like it - there may be a trick to it.

@DIY75 - no, already checked: my wife sometimes does the "cleaning run" with dishwasher empty, and sometimes the tray does not have too much spoons, so that spray arm does not fall off.

@Triplefault - I've added the picture of the replacement part in question. I'd say the picture shows the elements in 1:1 scale, so you can see it can't be anywhere else but the top.

Can you add a photo of the relevant, rather unusual, parts in situ?
